# Backslashes and brackets with sets

Tags: notation

I came upon the following expression but am not sure what it means:
$$i\in\Pi\;\backslash\;\{0\}$$
I understand that $i$ is an element in set $\Pi$, but please explain $\backslash\;\{0\}$.

Comment: Where have you seen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means ["relative complement."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) I always teach it as follows: Given two sets $X$ and $Y$, the set $X \setminus Y$ means the set that contains everything that is in $X$ but not in $Y$. So $X \setminus Y = X \cap Y^C.$ When first introducing it, I always speak it as "$X$ take out $Y$," as you are removing elements from the first that appear in the second.

The notation may not be nice, so some authors will literally just write a minus sign, i.e., $X - Y$. I find this a bit more intuitive.

In your case, when we write $i \in \Pi \setminus \{ 0 \}$, we say that $i$ is in $\Pi$ but is not zero.

Here's another example. Let $S = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$ and $T = \{2, 4 \}.$ Then $S \setminus T = \{ 1, 3, 5 \}.$ (Again, you can also write $S - T$ for this.)

By the way, to render the backslash with the correct spacing in this sense, use `\setminus` to produce, say, $S \setminus T.$